# How to set an array value in global variable React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating react native app. I want to set my array value into my variable that is declared into this.state:{current_Cat_id:'',}. my code is like :-

```
render() {
return(
          {this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index)=>
            <View key={Index}>      
                {dataImage['main-head'] != undefined && (
                        <View style={{marginRight:20,marginLeft:20,marginBottom:20,width:320,fontSize:16,color:'#000'}}>
                            {dataImage['main-head'].map((subsubchild, Index3)=>
                                <Text>{subsubchild['cat_name']} ({subsubchild['num_rows']})                             
                            </Text>                                                                         
                            )}
                        </View>                     

                )}  
                </View> 
             )}   
)
}
```

when i am getting values from loop than it should be set value in my variable i.e declared in this.state .
I have tried it like this:

```
 {this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index)=>
                <View key={Index}>      
                    {dataImage['main-head'] != undefined && (
                            <View style={{marginRight:20,marginLeft:20,marginBottom:20,width:320,fontSize:16,color:'#000'}}>
                                {dataImage['main-head'].map((subsubchild, Index3)=>
this.setState:({current_cat_id:subsubchild['cat_name']})
                                    <Text>{subsubchild['cat_name']} ({subsubchild['num_rows']})                             
                                </Text>                                                                         
                                )}
                            </View>                     

                    )}  
                    </View> 
                 )}
```

but can't succeeded . how can i do this

Comment: Hi Kiran, what are you trying to accomplish by putting that into your state? It actually goes against react principals to be settings your state in the render() function. The render() function should use the state to render the html and not modify the state at all. If you explain why you are trying to set the state maybe we can think of a way to do it outside of render() that makes more sense.

Comment: how can i use this.props.data.map outside of render ?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. For example, do you want to update the state every time the props are changed? Because then you can put the code in the lifecycle function componentWillReceieveProps. If you just want to set it in the beginning, you can put it in the componentWillMount

Comment: i have tried it in componentWillmoint like this:
this.props.data.map((dataImage)=>
alert(dataImage['main-head''])
)
but its return error

Comment: That should be fine and allow you to correctly set the state. Are you still running into an issue?

Comment: i have tried like this:-
  componentWillMount(){
   this.props.data((dataImage)=>
   alert(dataImage['ProductName'])
   )
   }

Comment: but its returning me nothing

Comment: i am trying like this:
  componentWillMount(){
   this.props.data.map((dataImage)=>
   this.setState({current_cat_id:dataImage['ProductName']});   
   )
   }
and its returning Unexpected token, expected ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiran,

The best practice is to not modify state in the render(). render() should use the state and props to determine what the rendered HTML is.

If you would like to set the state based on the props, the best practice for doing so is in either in the constructor or in the componentWillMount() life-cycle method. You would do something like this:

```
class ReactClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            # put initial values of state here or make them depend on props
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        # access this.props here and use this.setState as needed
    }
}
```

**Edit**

How about trying this to get the state to have an array based on the map:

```
componentWillMount() {
    var ids = [];
    this.props.data.map((dataImage) => {
        ids.push(dataImage['ProductName'])
    })
    this.setState({current_cat_id: ids})
}
```

This might not work exactly but this is the general approach I would recommend where you construct the list and then set the state at once.

Comment: i am trying like this:
 componentWillMount(){ this.props.data.map((dataImage)=> this.setState({current_cat_id:dataImage['ProductName']}); ) } and its returning Unexpected token, expected ,

Comment: Why are you setting the state while looping through the data? This will lead to the state being overridden on each iteration. After running the map, what do you want the value of this.state.current_cat_id to be?

Comment: in array i have category id and i want to set it in my varibale current_cat_id. i want to use it outside the map.

Comment: Do you want the current_cat_id to be a list of all the category ids?

Comment: i want to use value from outside the loop

Comment: my array have only one value {catid:123,catname:"t-shirs"}

Comment: array have only this
{"main-head":[{"cat_name":"Corner TV Stands, Units & Cabinets UK","catId":"88_307"}]}

Comment: I added an edit to my answer which generates a list in the map and then sets the state outside the map

Comment: so i want to set catid  in my variable. array have only one catid its not have array like 
{"main-head":[{"cat_name":"Corner TV Stands, Units & Cabinets UK","catId":"88_307"},{"cat_name":"abc","catId":"88_308"}]}

Comment: thank you so much , I have last query. can i use it like this
componentWillMount() {
    var ids = [];
    this.props.data.map((dataImage) => {
  dataImage['main-head'].map((subchild) =>{
   ids.push(subchild['catid']) 
   })
        
    })
    this.setState({current_cat_id: ids})
}
becuase my actual array is like:
[{"catsid":[{"proid":"88_52","category_name":"Glass TV Stands"},{"proid":"88_306","category_name":"High Gloss TV Stands"},{"proid":"88_305","category_name":"Wooden TV Stands"}]},{"main-head":[{"cat_name":"Corner TV Stands, Units & Cabinets UK","catid":"88_307"}]}]

Comment: but its returning blank page. even not showing any error

Comment: can you put console.logs to print out ids and also see what is running

Comment: no, actually when i enable debug JS Remotly than showing error not connected with server. some problem there. any other idea ?

Comment: Awesome! Good luck :)